# Почему функции cos(), sin(), atant2() преобразуют long double в double?

Tags: c++, функции, double, преобразование-типов

Пишу проект, в котором необходима большая точность вычислений угла, а так же cos и sin. Обнаружил, что значения, передаваемые мной в приведённые функции, преобразуются из long double в double (Мне это даже компилятор подсвечивает).
Я нашёл определение этих функций, они имеют перегрузку с параметрами long double, однако, почему то происходит преобразование в double.

Выглядит примерно так:

```
ax += F*cos(angle) / Objects[i].getMass();/*ax, angle и mass - переменные типа long double*/
```

Тут же я получаю предупреждение: *implicit conversion loses floating-point precision: 'long double' to 'double'*

В чём дело?

Comment: Ну так а где код? Где список включаемых заголовков? Где все остальное? Перегруженные функции из заголовка `<cmath>` называются `std::cos`, `std::sin`, `std::atan2` и т.д. А вы что вызываете?

Comment: Да, именно их я и вызываю, простите, что не уточнил.

Comment: Тут был комментарий про cosl, sinl, atan2l. Это сработало, спасибо, почему его нет тут больше?

Comment: Вы уверены что именно их вы и вызываете? Я не вижу `std::` в вашей строчке кода.

Comment: "cosl, sinl, atan2l" не являются ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Не знал, что это необходимо, они итак вызывались.

Comment: Что значит "они итак вызывались"??? Вы же сами написали в вопросе, что всегда выбиралась именно `double` версия, независимо от типа аргумента. Что говорит о том, что перегруженные функции НЕ рассматривались.

Comment: Да, с std предупреждений не выдаёт как и с l-функциями, но, похоже, пора создавать новую тему, так как точность всё равно не та, что мне нужна. Если в sin передаёт Пи, то он возвращает не ноль, а что то очень близкое к нулю

Comment: "Если в sin передаёт Пи..." Это как это вы его туда передаете? Число Пи невозможно представить точно в плавающем формате. Вы передаете "что-то очень близкое" к Пи - получаете "что-то очень близкое" к нулю.

Comment: Тут я более подробно объяснил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990413/%d0%9d%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-atan2long-double-y-long-double-x-sin-%d0%b8-cos-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd    Спасибо вам за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Перегруженные функции объявлены в пространстве `std` заголовка `<cmath>`, т.е. называются `std::cos`, `std::sin`, `std::atan2`. Именно их и надо вызывать.