# Низкая точность atan2(long double y, long double x), sin() и cos() соответственно

Tags: c++, функции

Имею необходимость получать точные значения sin и cos угла, использую для этого long double. Проблема в том, что даже при такой точности, при передаче угла, равного Пи в sin, имею ненулевое значение. Выяснилось, что проблема в функции atan2(). При гарантированном угле 180 градусов, он выдаёт значение, равное:
3.14159265358979323851

При этом число Пи до этого знака: 
3.14159265358979323846

Отличаются последние два знака.

Но проблема не заключается только лишь в этом.
Если в sin() передавать указанное выше значение Pi, функция вернёт нечто очень близкое к нулю, но никак не ноль: 1.22465e-16

Как быть в такой ситуации, как повысить точность вычислений?

Comment: Интересно, а *какая* точность вам нужна? Типа, если синус будет не 10 в -16, а 10 в -25 - этого достаточно или нет?... И *для чего* может быть нужна такая точность?...

Comment: Для того, чтобы точки, находящиеся на одной горизонтали  (по углом 0 градусов друг к другу), имели только горизонтальное движение под действием силы тяготения. Сейчас же у меня получается, что точки движутся горизонтально, но с небольшой скоростью по y (хотя угол между ними 0). В некоторых ситуациях это абсолютно недопустимо в рамках моего проекта, так как теряется весь смысл моделирования.

Comment: Честно говоря, ваш вопрос про точность поставил меня в ступор. Но, вероятно, ответ таков: достаточная, чтобы выполнялись условия выше

Comment: О каком "повышении точности" идет речь? Ваши ожидания нереалистичны. Никакого "числа Пи" и математически точного поведения в данном контексте быть не может. Так не бывает. Наоборот, получить "ноль" в таком случае вы сможете только при *понижении* точности вычислений, то есть из-за округления.

Comment: Что вы моделируете, если не секрет? Задачу N тел?

Comment: Я представляю себе это как то, что atan2 посчитает значение с бОльшим количеством знаков после запятой (где два последние знака могут так же не совпадать с Пи), sin съест этот результат, отбросит последние знаки, и посчитает уже с корректным значением числа Пи до определённого знака, иными словами, выдаст ноль на: 3.14159265358979323846

Comment: Это физический симулятор, который в самом простом виде моделирует движение и взаимодействие объектов обладающих массой и зарядом (заряд необязателен). Во многих симуляциях было замечено, как объект, который должен двигаться лишь по горизонтали, накапливает вертикальную скорость и уходит туда, куда не надо.

Comment: В общем случае, да, задача N тел

Comment: Тогда возникает вопрос, откуда у вас вообще берутся какие-то углы? Вы случайно не храните вектор скорости как угол и модуль скорости? Если да, то храните скорость как пару чисел - проекции скорости на оси X и Y, и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Да, именно так я и делаю! У меня имеются проекции ускорения и скорости. Со скоростью всё ясно: прибавить текущее значение какой то проекции к соответствующей проекции ускорения. В случае же с ускорением, я сначала высчитываю Результирующую силу, а потом домножаю её либо на sin либо на cos, чтобы получить проекцию ускорения

Comment: Но вы вот сейчас сказали, и я задумался: почему бы мне не расчитывать силы отдельно по X и по Y?

Comment: В общем случаи такого типа вопрос должен быть дополнен примером: с аргументами и ожидаемым результатом.   Согласен с HolyBlackCat  и с   AnT

Comment: число ПИ бесконечное, отсюда и от того что double это такая эмуляция вещественных чисел и получаются 12e-17. Ну то есть вы всегда будете получать какое-то приближение с какой-то точностью вместо истинного (аналитического) значения 0 для `sin(M_PI)`;

Comment: Всё, проблема решена. Спасибо всем, кто помогал, отдельное спасибо HolyBlackCat за весьма очевидную мысль.

Comment: И простите за неграмотную подачу вопроса, я постараюсь исправиться

Answer (score 0):

Как получить ноль, если значение ниже например 0.001? Написать `свою  atan`

```
auto my_atan(const std::valarray<long double>& v1, const std::valarray<long double>& v2)
{
    auto v = atan2(v1, v2);
    v = v.apply([](long double d) { return d < 0.001 ? 0 : d; });   
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Если не важна скорость, то можно использовать длинную арифметику. На С++ множество реализаций, в том числе в boost, быть может есть и реализации тригонометрических функций. Ваше значение 1.22465e-16 как раз лежит где-то в области машинного нуля.

Comment: Хорошо, я рассмотрю этот вариант, спасибо. Но есть ли вариант, при котором скорость страдает не сильно? Она тоже имеет не второстепенную роль для меня.

Comment: Популярные библиотеки: The GNU MP Bignum Library, The GNU MPFR Library. [Perfomance тест](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-3.1.0/timings.html), может быть не актуален.